# for inner product in pytorch, `dot` and `inner` give wildly different results with dtype = torch.bfloat

Tags: python, pytorch, precision, matrix-multiplication

I have two 1-dimensional PyTorch tensors (of type `bfloat16`), and I want to compute their inner/dot product.

Should I use `torch.dot` or `torch.inner`?  I thought it shouldn't really matter which one, but they give me wildly different results. I experimented with some other methods too, and found that some behave like `torch.dot` and some behave like `torch.inner` (see comments in code below).   Why is this? And **which is the right one to use?**

```py
import torch
torch.manual_seed(17) # set seed for replication

dtype=torch.bfloat16
# make two 1d tensors 
a = torch.rand([10000], dtype=dtype)
b = torch.rand([10000], dtype=dtype)

x1 = torch.dot(a,b)
# or, equivalently:
# x1 = torch.matmul(a,b)
# x1 = a @ b

x2 = torch.inner(a,b)
# or equivalently: 
# x2 = (a*b).sum(-1)
# x2 = torch.mul(a,b).sum(-1)
# x2 = torch.matmul(a.unsqueeze(0),
#                   b.unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze()
```

The results are not equal.  They're not even close.

```py
print(f"""{x1 = }\n{x2 = }
{torch.equal(x1, x2) = }
{torch.isclose(x1, x2) = }""")
```

> ```
> x1 = tensor(256., dtype=torch.bfloat16)
> x2 = tensor(2464., dtype=torch.bfloat16)
> torch.equal(x1, x2) = False
> torch.isclose(x1, x2) = tensor(False)
> ```

However, if I set `dtype=torch.float` instead of `bfloat16`, they end up *nearly* the same (still some differences due, I suppose, to numerical instability).

> ```
> x1 = tensor(2477.7292, dtype=torch.bfloat16)
> x2 = tensor(2477.7295, dtype=torch.bfloat16)
> torch.equal(x1, x2) = False
> torch.isclose(x1, x2) = tensor(True)
> ```

What is the best way to get the inner product reliably, if the type is/may be bfloat16?

---

EDIT:

Python 3.10.10 on CPU.

Answer (score 4):

I did some digging but don't really have a satisfying answer. Unfortunately, it all depends how the order of operations are done internally and it can even differ between the BLAS implementation between CPU and GPU. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70650236/why-does-pytorch-matmul-get-different-results-when-executed-on-cpu-and-gpu) and [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-different-results-when-multiplying-in-cpu-than-in-gpu/1356/4).

But to bring a bit of new information, the result of `256` is no coincidence, it's what you get when you sum a lot of numbers smaller than one in sequential order using `bfloat16`.

```
a = torch.rand([10000], dtype=dtype)
x = torch.tensor(0, dtype=dtype)
for a1 in a:
    x += a1
```

This order of operation is very bad for floats with small fractional precision such as `bfloat16` and this is what must be happening internally in `torch.matmul`.

Edit:

And even funnier:

```
print(torch.tensor(257., dtype=torch.bfloat16))
```

> tensor(256., dtype=torch.bfloat16)

Comment: I'm still unsure what to do though (but thanks very much for the links and information). I suppose doing a dot/inner product of two vectors in bfloat16 is unreliable... but from a practical perspective, if one must do such an operation, is it true that `a.inner(b)` is in general a better choice than `a.dot(b)` (as it seems here), or does this depend on whether you're on CPU or GPU, or some other considerations?